# Cannot find symbol setForegroundServiceBehavior

Tags: java, android, android-notifications

I have a foreground service. When it started, notification showed with delay. Then I searched this issue. I found setForegroundServiceBehavior. But when I started the app, I have mistake that setForegroundServiceBehavior cannot find symbol. Why?

```java
NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL_ID)
                .setForegroundServiceBehavior(FOREGROUND_SERVICE_IMMEDIATE)
                .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcherr)
                .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(getString(R.string.str)))
                .setContentText(getString(R.string.str))
                .setAutoCancel(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

[Appcompat](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/appcompat)'s library version you are using is too old. You need to switch to a newer one.

Comment: Do you by any chance know in which Appcompat version this method was added?

Comment: @TalMantelmakher I'm using this: `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'`. Method `setForegroundServiceBehavior` is defined there. I think you need to just use the latest version available. It should not prevent you from supporting old Androids :)